# How do I remove row context coming from a user selection when using SUMX in a DAX measure in SSAS Tabular?

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas-tabular

How do I remove the row context from SUMX so that it will include all of the records of the table variable it is iterating?

I tried this, but it had no effect (wrapping the table with a FILTER to say "All Period Date Values") -- which is still not ultimately what I want:

```
SUMX(FILTER(varCoverageTableYTD
     , ALL('Equipment Cost on Rent With Branch'[PeriodDate]) 
     ,    DIVIDE([Days on Rent with Branch], [Billable Days with Branch]) 
       *   DIVIDE([Billable Days with Branch], [Total Days with Branch]) 
       *  'Equipment Cost on Rent With Branch'[EquipmentCostForCORMeasure_CCUR] 
     ))
```

I had previously taken a different approach. I had believed my problem was a filter context, and I removed it. Having done so, I am left to assume that it's the SUMX iterator which is inheriting row context.

Here is the full measure definition. I do believe I have isolated the problem to SUMX (as I described already). However, there may be benefit in showing the code for the entire definition:

```
// Convert the user selected period into Begin and End Dates 

   VAR varLastDateYTD = LASTDATE(DATESYTD('Calendar'[Calendar Date]))
   VAR varFirstDateYTD = DATE(YEAR(varLastDateYTD), 1, 1)

   // Remove the filter context which is coming from the user selection 

   VAR varCoverageTableAllDates = CALCULATETABLE('Equipment Cost on Rent With Branch'                             
                               , ALL('Equipment Cost on Rent With Branch'[PeriodDate])                               )  

// Filter the table to the calculated Begin and End Dates 

   VAR varCoverageTableYTD = FILTER(varCoverageTableAllDates                                      
                             , 'Equipment Cost on Rent With Branch'[PeriodDate] <= varLastDateYTD 
                            && 'Equipment Cost on Rent With Branch'[PeriodDate] >= varFirstDateYTD                               )  

// Iterate over the new table, calculating on a per row basis. 
// Does SUMX get a row context from the user selection? 
// My result is limited to the user selected period. 

   RETURN SUMX(varCoverageTableYTD,
          , DIVIDE([Days on Rent with Branch], [Billable Days with Branch]) 
        *   DIVIDE([Billable Days with Branch], [Total Days with Branch]) 
        *  'Equipment Cost on Rent With Branch'[EquipmentCostForCORMeasure_CCUR]   
        )
```

[image: Portion of the Model in my question]

Comment: can you post your data model diagram?

Comment: Thank you. The model is quite large. I posted a pic showing the relationship of concern. (FYI: There are no bi-directional filters anywhere... yet.)

Comment: it might be necessary to see formulas for [Days on Rent with Branch], [Billable Days with Branch], [Total Days with Branch] measures

Comment: Each is simple: Measure = SUM([it's column value]), such that [Days on Rent] = SUM('Coverage Table'[FactDaysOnRent])

Comment: On that line of reasoning (context transition from the measure), I had previously tried doing this with YTD measures using YTD DAX functions, and that did cause some other challenges.

Comment: New thought: SUMX will deliver a non-scalar result that can integrate with the user context --slicers, etc., right? I think that SUMX is delivering the full result, and maybe the presentation layer says let's display the portion of the value for the selected filter? I think I can test this by wrapping SUMX, maybe?

Comment: @RADO Thank you for your comments. I was asking the wrong question. I am not properly removing the user selected filter. Thanks again for your collaboration and willingness to help!

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help better - it's hard to advise on large models without seeing them. On a separate note, is there a reason you calculate varCoverageTableYTD in 4 steps instead of 1? Also, why do you divide by [Billable Days with Branch] since it multiplies the result in the next step and cancels it out??

Comment: That's a fun question. I got mocked by my client for asking the same thing. I wrote the formula out in hand writing and cancelled out the common factors. They looked at me like I was from outer space. (Math?) I put it back in there because it makes them feel better. I was asked to refrain from sharing complex math formulas. I truly, actually was. "It's too technical."

Comment: As for the four steps, for debugging (and readability, perhaps?): remove selected filter, apply filter based on variables, iterate and calculate, then return the result. This pattern can get copied and reused for a couple other similar measures (different granularity, different measurement period), and having all of the steps chopped up like that makes it easier to re-use because the summary changes or the filtering changes. In a few weeks, this (and everything else) will be managed by their in-house guy. I think this will help him out.

Comment: Clients can be... entertaining. I once developed a model to roll financials along a bill of materials tree. It was very hard, as BOM is an unbalanced hierarchy with undefined depth (i.e, imagine a tree that describes all components of a car!), and I was proud to build a solution. But when I showed it to a client, the only thing they asked: "why amounts in your report don't have dollar signs?"